# Flot chart lines with AJAX, PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, flot

I'm using Flot plugin to get a chart line with two lines (Sales and Purchases) like [this example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/index.html) but data is in mysql database and being received via AJAX. So I have this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="graph" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
```

**PHP:**

**sales.php**

```
<?php 
  $sql = "SELECT * from sales where YEAR(date)='2013'";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  $return = [];

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $return[] = [$row['date'],$row['amount']];
}
echo json_encode(array("label"=>"Sales","data"=>$return));
?>
```

**purchases.php**

```
<?php 
  $sql = "SELECT * from purchases where YEAR(date)='2013'";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  $return = [];

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $return[] = [$row['date'],$row['amount']];
}
echo json_encode(array("label"=>"Purchases","data"=>$return));
?>
```

So, in my JS code I get this data via AJAX and put it a Flot chart line enabling tooltip:

```
var purchases,sales;

    $.ajax({url: "purchases.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resp)
        {
            purchases = resp.data; //Showing result:[["2013-02-01","52"],["2013-03-01","40"],["2013-03-28","200"]]          
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "sales.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resp)
        {
            sales = resp.data; //Showing result: [["2013-02-05","502"],["2013-03-16","240"],["2013-03-21","260"]]       
        }
    });

var dataset = [
        {
            label: "Purchases",
            data: purchases,
        },
        {
            label: "Sales",
            data: sales,
        }
    ];

var chart_plot_01_settings = {
      series: {
        lines: {
          show: true,
          fill: true
        },
        splines: {
          show: false,
          tension: 0.4,
          lineWidth: 1,
          fill: 0.4
        },
        points: {
          radius: 3,
          show: true 
        },
        shadowSize: 2 
      },
      grid: { 
        verticalLines: true,
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true,
        tickColor: "#d5d5d5",
        borderWidth: 1,
        color: '#717171'
      },
      colors: ["rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.38)", "rgba(3, 88, 106, 0.38)"],
      xaxis: {
        tickColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.06)",
        mode: "time",
        tickSize: [1, "month"],
        axisLabel: "Date",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
        axisLabelPadding: 10
      },
      yaxis: {
        ticks: 8,
        axisLabel: "Amount",
        tickColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.06)",
      },
      tooltip: true, 
    }

if ($("#graph").length){
        $.plot( $("#graph"), dataset,  chart_plot_01_settings );

        $("<div id='tooltip'></div>").css({
            position: "absolute",
            display: "none",
            border: "1px solid #fdd",
            padding: "2px",
            "background-color": "#fee",
            opacity: 0.80
        }).appendTo("body");

        $("#graph").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {

            if (item) {
                var x = item.datapoint[0],
                    y = item.datapoint[1];

                var date = new Date(x);                 

                $("#tooltip").html("Date: " +x + " Amount: "+y).css({top: item.pageY+5, left: item.pageX+5}).fadeIn(200);

            } else {
                $("#tooltip").hide();
            }

        });
    }
```

The problem is chart line doesn't display any data, It's in blank. I added a line `console.log(sales)` after `if ($("#graph").length){` line and it shows **undefined** in console but it shows data if I put result in console inside success AJAX function.

[image]

How can I fix it? I'd like some help.

**UPDATE**

I modified PHP code line:

```
$return[] = [strtotime($row['date'])*1000,$row['amount']];
```

I modified JS code adding a **show_chart** function:

```
function show_chart(labell,dataa) { 
    var dataset = [{label: labell,data: dataa}];

    var chart_plot_01_settings = {
      series: {
        lines: {
          show: true,
          fill: true
        },
        splines: {
          show: false,
          tension: 0.4,
          lineWidth: 1,
          fill: 0.4
        },
        points: {
          radius: 3,
          show: true 
        },
        shadowSize: 2 
      },
      grid: { 
        verticalLines: true,
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true,
        tickColor: "#d5d5d5",
        borderWidth: 1,
        color: '#717171'
      },
      colors: ["rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.38)", "rgba(3, 88, 106, 0.38)"],
      xaxis: {
        tickColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.06)",
        mode: "time",
        tickSize: [1, "month"],
        //tickLength: 10,
        axisLabel: "Date",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
        axisLabelPadding: 10
      },
      yaxis: {
        ticks: 8,
        axisLabel: "Amount",
        tickColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.06)",
      },
      tooltip: true,
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.plot($("#graph"), dataset, chart_plot_01_settings);

        //Tooltip
        $("<div id='tooltip'></div>").css({
            position: "absolute",
            display: "none",
            border: "1px solid #fdd",
            padding: "2px",
            "background-color": "#fee",
            opacity: 0.80
        }).appendTo("body");

        $("#graph").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {

            if (item) {
                var x = item.datapoint[0],
                    y = item.datapoint[1];

                var date = new Date(x);

                $("#tooltip").html("Date: " + ('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/'+ date.getFullYear()+ " | Amount: "+y).css({top: item.pageY+5, left: item.pageX+5}).fadeIn(200);

            } else {
                $("#tooltip").hide();
            }

        });
    });

} //show chart

var purchases,sales;

    $.ajax({url: "purchases.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resp)
        {
            purchases = resp.data;
            var label1 = resp.label;
            show_chart(label1,purchases);       
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "sales.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resp)
        {
            sales = resp.data;
            var label2 = resp.label;
            show_chart(label2,sales);
        }
    });
```

But the problem it's only showing **Sales** or **Purchases** chart line and I want to show **both** chart lines (**Sales and Purchases**) like [this example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/index.html).

How can I fix it?

Comment: have you tried to instantiate the flot chart inside the success block of the ajax itself? imo one of the most straightforward way (since you need server response to be complete first anyway). define the options up top, make the ajax call, then after success, instantiate the flot. (what i would do). and check the console for errors too btw

Comment: Did you print `$return` array in sale.php and purchase.php?

Comment: @ArshadShaikh Yes, and I get the info, but it doesn't show in chart.

Comment: @Ghost Yes, I tried that too, I put the flot chart inside success and also variable dataset but it get worse showing an error

Comment: Try with dummy data in dataset and check the actual data and your data from ajax resposne.

Comment: @NekoLopez issue is because your chart initialization script will be executed before your ajax response received.

Comment: To solve this issue make one function to reinitialize your chart and call this function in `success` of ajax

Comment: @B.Desai correct, make one function and send your ajax response and reinitialise chart.

Comment: @B.Desai Could you give me an example, please?

Comment: @B.Desai I updated my question adding that function but it's only showing one chart line

Comment: @ArshadShaikh I updated my question adding that function but it's only showing one chart line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could resolve it joining my 2 php files in one and put a final array:

```
echo json_encode(array($return,$returnn));
```

In AJAX success:

```
success: function(resp)
{
    var result1 = resp[0];//purchases
    var result2 = resp[1];//sales
    show_chart(result1,result2);
}
```

And in **show_cart** function:

```
function show_chart(data1,data2) {
    var dataset = [{label: "Purchases",data: data1},{label: "Sales",data: data2}];
    //and continues...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your time data has the wrong format, Flot needs JavaScript timestamps. Instead of

```
[["2013-02-01","52"],["2013-03-01","40"],["2013-03-28","200"]]
```

you need

```
[[1359676800000,"52"],[1362096000000,"40"],[1364428800000,"200"]]
```

Use

```
strtotime("2013-02-01 UTC") * 1000
```

in your PHP code to generate the timestamps (see [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I updated my question adding that correction and a JS function but it's only showing one chart line